# ImportError: cannot import name PyFontify

Tags: pip, reportlab

I am installing `django-easy-pdf`, `xhtml2pdf` and `reportlab` using `pip` I installed the following in a virtual environment.:

```
$ pip install django-easy-pdf
$ pip install "xhtml2pdf>=0.0.6" "reportlab>=2.7,<3"
```

But after the testing, there is an import error that has following message:

> from reportlab.lib import PyFontify
>
> ImportError: cannot import name PyFontify

Oh, I nearly forgot, when I'm installing the `reportlab`, this came up in the middle of the setup:

```
running build_ext
building '_rl_accel' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
----------------------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of reportlab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the packages and their dependencies and installing it again.